# Implementation of new module in zend skeleton application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have followed the new Module creation request. http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html

But I am getting below error.

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Request you to assist me in resolving this issue. What is required to sorted out this issue.

[URL loading issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6dUW.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some source code.

Comment: You might forget to add `invokables` in `module.config.php`.

Comment: Application directory structure is C:\xampp\htdocs\MyZendApp\module\Album\config\module.config.php and I have added below code in module.config file.                                                                                                      return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
         ),
     ),

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola, could you pls let me know which source code you require?   I implemented new module as per below tutorial: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html

Comment: I have followed the same tutorial and I stuck on the same problem than I found that its not working because of invokables. Can you provide me the code of 2 config files global and module.

Comment: Here is the code of application.config file

Comment: application.config file code is return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
  'DoctrineModule',
  'DoctrineORMModule',
  'CsnUser'
    ), and module.config file code is return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'CsnUser\Controller\Index' => 'CsnUser\Controller\IndexController',
            'CsnUser\Controller\Registration' => 'CsnUser\Controller\RegistrationController',
            'CsnUser\Controller\Admin' => 'CsnUser\Controller\AdminController',
        ),
    ),

Comment: Thanks for your help Indrasinh.                                                                                                                                       Also I am unable to install coolcsn/csn-user package using php composer.phar require coolcsn/csn-user:dev-master. 

It throws an exception  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting. 

It seems package version Issue. Could you please let me know what is the stable version is available and composer command to install it.

Comment: Did you run composer install from your project root??

Comment: Might be you forget to add routes for album module please check http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html